# how i can styling primeng p-table inner paginator?

Tags: css, angular, primeng

```
<p-table [value]="rows" [styleClass]="'inner_table'" [paginator]="true" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[5,10,25]" [rows]="5">...</p-table>
```

i tryed many option:

```
.inner_table .ui-paginator {
    background-color: red !important;
}

.ui-paginator-pages .ui-state-active {
    background-color:red;
}
```

etc. but they didn't work. paginator stay just white.

[image]

my styles don't apply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the styles **in the file** "styles.css", not in the app-component.css
BTW: the version 15.1.0, has change the name of the classes, e.g.

This .css

```
.inner_table .p-paginator .p-paginator-pages .p-paginator-page.p-highlight
{
  background:red;
  color:white;
}
.inner_table .p-paginator
{
  background:silver;
}
.inner_table .p-paginator .p-paginator-current,.inner_table .p-paginator .p-paginator-pages .p-paginator-page,
.inner_table .p-paginator .p-paginator-first, .inner_table .p-paginator .p-paginator-prev, .inner_table .p-paginator .p-paginator-next, .inner_table .p-paginator .p-paginator-last
{
  color:white;

}
```

Give this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tabledoc-demo-i7dlxb?file=src%2Fstyles.css)

**Update** for prime-ng 8 you can try

```
.inner_table .ui-paginator
{
   background:red;
}
.inner_table .ui-paginator .ui-paginator-pages .ui-paginator-page.ui-state-active
{
   background:red;
}
```

Comment: Tried it, still doesn't work unfortunately. I am using version 8. i added "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/rhea/theme.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css", in angular.json, could it interfere with assigning new styles?

Comment: I update the answer for prime-ng 8.2.9 (Really I'm not prety sure that works). As general rule, a .css more specific have priority over the same with less specific (when we add  a class becomes more specific, e.g. `.custom .oneclass` it's more specific than `.oneclass`). So if we use F12 and select any element, we can see the "class" (can be several classes). Remember in angular.json add also the "styles.css" (that is where we write the class)

Comment: This helped, thanks. the only thing is that of course I don't want to specify styles in style.css, it's weird. Surely there is no way to specify them in the component file?

Comment: You can not put the code in your component.css :(. But you can use [ViewEncapsulation.None](https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation) but **be carefull** this makes that **all** the .css in your component was a .css "global". That's: if you add in your component `h1{color:red}` all the h1 in your aplication will be red.